# How can I display a grid of all possible colors?

Tags: c#, colors, grid, selector, picker

How can I create a grid of all possible RGB color combinations in a logical sequence?
Something like this:

[image]
Using 256 values per color would yield (256^3=) 16,777,216 possible colors that could be arranged into a (sqrt of 16,777,216=) 4,096 x 4,096 square.

I know how to make an array of colors and then display them, but what I'm asking for is the logic behind making smooth transitions between the colors.

Comment: You want to make a [color tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_tool). Color is a very interesting but complicated matter... Have fun :D

Answer (score 4):

Don't think in RGB, think in the HSL (Hue, Saturation, lightness) or HSV color space.  They are much closer to what humans perceive as 'close' to each other.

To get the colors like the ones in your example:

1. Leave Saturation at '1'.
2. To go across (different colors, RED->YELLOW->GREEN->ETC), increase the 'Hue'.
3. To go down (where the color gets darker) decrease the lightness.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) is an article on HSL and HSV color space.  In that article they have some conversion algorithms back to RGB, but [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html) is a nice easy article for the conversion in C.

EDIT: And [one in c#](http://www.splinter.com.au/converting-hsv-to-rgb-colour-using-c/)

Comment: This wouldn’t be all possible colors though. You’d be leaving out all saturated variants. 

You need 16m+ pixels to view all, though you couldn’t represent them all continuously afaik in a 2D space.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reach *all* possible colors with an arrangement like in the linked image on a 4kX4k square because the RGB colors displayed by computers are in a three-dimensional space. That's why there are different color models in graphics programs which usually display three value selectors or at least pull out one dimension to a linear selector control and leave the other two dimensions in a squared control.

Sometimes you also see an arrangement in a hexagonal control or a triangular color and a separate brightness selector.

The linked image misses the grey colors completely. It is actually a combined selector for Hue and Lightness in HSL color space. The middle line with the intense colors can be easily determined with starting one base color, step by step adding the next base color, when reaching the max value reducing the first color, then transition with the same schema to the third and finally back to the first color. On the way to the top, there's a linear transition to white, on the way down to black.

In the end you have all colors on the six bounding planes in the color space but the whole space between the planes is not yet covered. For that, you need a separate selector for the saturation of the color. Reducing the saturation from the maximum level covers the grey colors.

If you really want all colors on a squared space, you can create blocks of 256x256 in size that repeat again and again with slight addition of the third color.

Answer (score 0):

In general representing 3d space on a plane is hard especially if you want to see something inisde non-transparent cloud... So dropping intensity maybe one approach.

Look into HSI/HSL/HSV - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSI_color_space.